# CORS in local webview

Tags: react-native

I have a react native app that loads a local page in a webview. This page has normal javascript files that try to load other local files in the same folder using `XMLHttpRequest` but are unable to do so due to the CORS restrictions.

This is how the webview is loading the content:
`source={{ uri: 'file:///android_asset/viewer.html' }}`

Does anyone knows a workaround for this? Either disabling CORS or loading the local content with http will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the option `allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs` was supposed to allow local file access, but it didn't. The view executes before the security settings are updated.

The following workaround worked for me: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/656#issuecomment-551312436